# SSL Offloading Problems since Shopware 6.4.12.0

Tags: ssl, traefik, shopware6

We are running Shopware 6 on a Apache HTTP webserver in Docker on our CI. Then Traefik is doing the SSL termination.

Now on a new Shopware 6.4.12.0 setup we have the problem, that the admin interface which is accessed via `https://example.com/admin` tries to load its resources from `http://example.com/admin`.

We believe that is because Shopware sees only the HTTP connection and does not know how to construct the right URLs.

`APP_URL` in the `.env` is set to `https://example.com`

Is this a new behavior in 6.4.12.0 ? How can the SSL offloading be configured?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like we simply forgot a `.env` setting on the new instance

```
TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,172.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: This should solve the issue, since it's a symfony standard configuration for proxies that terminate SSL: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html

Comment: Yes it did :-) Thanks for the additional link.